# How to bind the second same type of instance to kernel and distinguish them in Ninject?

Tags: kernel, ninject, bind

I'm working on automating Windows app by using White framework. Application is a class of White framework.

During my test, I get an Application instance by a the method getApplication(), bind it to kernel, put in serviceLocator and keep this instance as Singleton:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<Application>().ToMethod(ctx => getApplication()).InSingletonScope();            
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
```

Whenever I need to get the application, I use this code:

```
Application application = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Application>();
```

It works fine to me so far.

But after a few steps, I need get another instance of Application which is different from the 1st Application instance.

How can I bind this second instance of Application to kernel with ServiceLocator? and how to get the second instance by using service Locator(as the 2 instances have the same type)?

Thanks a million for any help in advance.

Comment: should I use the "Name" method like:  "kernel.Bind<Application>().ToMethod(ctx => getApplication()).InSingletonScope().Name("app1");" And when I need to get it, I will use: Application application1 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Application>("app1");

Comment: It looks like the above solution works...